# There are 2 classes , how do I use object of below class in above class?

Tags: c++, oop

For example, I have 2 classes as defined in following order...

```
class A
{
     int value;

     printValue(B b)
     {
        cout << b.value
     }
};

class B  
{
   int value;

   printValue(A a)
   {
      cout << a.value;
   }

}
```

How can I use the B object in A, as B definition is below ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can separate declaration and implementation of the classes, forward declare them in the declaration header files, and use references in the functions.

file A.h

```
class B; // forward declaration
class A {
  public:
     int value;
     void printValue(const B& b) const; // pass by reference
};
```

file B.h

```
class A; // forward declaration
class B  {
  public:
   int value;
   void printValue(const A& a) const; // pass by reference
};
```

Then, have separate implementation files. For example, `A`'s implementation file `A.cpp`:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void A::printValue(const B& b) const {
   std::cout << b.value;
}
```

and similarly for `B.cpp`.

Note that I have fixed the missing return types for the `printValue` functions, and made those functions `const`.

Comment: Isn't there any way, I can put both classes in same cpp file and achieve what I want ?

Comment: @user183177 probably, what exactly do you want to achieve? All code in one file? If so, it would have to be a header because the client code will need the class declarations.